# Crossentropy of softmax function derivative explanation

Tags: machine-learning

Following these calculations:
https://sebastianraschka.com/faq/docs/softmax_regression.html
,
I am a bit confused about the last equation[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3ZkF.png) .
Imagine I have a X which is of the shape (300, 7), y (which is one hot encoded) is of the shape (300, 3) and the weights matrix W is of the shape (7, 3). How would I compute the W', that is, the gradients of all w_j? Also, I don't get what is xi in the equation, if it is ith example.